# Adding Linear Feature From PostGIS to Leaflet

Tags: php, ajax, leaflet, postgis

I managed to add a PostGIS point feature to leaflet, but I am having trouble adding a linear feature from PostGIS to Leaflet. I am able to see the relational data in the alert window when I use `alert(response)`, but I cant seem to get it to draw on the map. Is there a special way I need to symbolize a line feature?

The following is the code I am using (which worked fine for a PostGIS point feature):

```
//PHP    
<?php
    $dsn = "pgsql:host=xxxxx;dbname=postgres;port=5432";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'postgres', 'xxxxxx', $opt);

    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT *, ST_AsGeoJSON(geom,5) AS geojson FROM testlyr");
    $features=[];
    foreach($result AS $row) {
        unset($row['geom']);
        $geometry=$row['geojson']=json_decode($row['geojson']);
        unset($row['geojson']);
        $feature=["type"=>"Feature", "geometry"=>$geometry, "properties"=>$row];
        array_push($features, $feature);
    }
$featureCollection=["type"=>"FeatureCollection", "features"=>$features];
echo json_encode($featureCollection);

?>
```

_

```
//JS
function mylineStyle(feature) {
  return {
    color: "#3388ff",
    weight: 10,
  };
}

$.ajax({
  url: "load_attractions.php",
  success: function (response) {
    jsnCities = JSON.parse(response);
    lyrCities = L.geoJSON(jsnCities, { style: mylineStyle }).addTo(map);
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert("ERROR: " + error);
  },
});
```

-

```
//Output of console.log() JSON response 
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[-10616750.46022,3451527.81212],[-10616193.63558,3451197.53649],[-10615872.3906,3451772.85539],[-10615154.94348,3451495.84996],[-10615283.44147,3451080.34194],[-10615626.10278,3450696.79619]]]},"properties":{"id":1}}]}
```

Comment: Any errors in your [browser's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)?

Comment: Thank you for your response! There are no errors in the console. I used the same exact code to successfully draw a PostGIS point feature in the Leaflet map. For the linear layer all I changed was the table name in the SQL statement in the PHP code. Is there something I need to change to display PostGIS linear and polygon features in Leaflet? I am so close, but I must be missing something here.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the `console.log()` output of the JSON response. There are no obvious mistakes, though.

Comment: I added the console.log() output of the JSON response in my original post above. There is only one feature.

Comment: Oh, your GeoJSON is not compliant because the coordinates are not (unprojected) lat-long as the specs say.

Comment: Ivan you are a genius!! Not sure how I missed that! Thank you thank you thank you for your help! How do i mark your answer as the correct answer??

Comment: You can turn this information into your own answer, explaining the actions you took to make your PHP spit out lat-long geojson; that'll be the most useful to others.

Comment: How do I give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Sanchez figured out the coordinates were not in lat/long as the specs require. Works perfectly now!!